# How to get data from a.py to import into b.py

Tags: python-3.x

if i have 2 python files **a.py** and **b.py**.

**a.py** is data input, and the **b.py** is processing file of the data input ( actualy i have few kind of data input besides a.py).

inside **a.py** there are : *aaa=int(input("value aaa"))* , *aab=int(input("value aab"))*,... *etc*

How to get the data input *aaa, aab, etc* in **a.py** calculated into **b.py** file?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my English, I don't know it so well to avoid mistakes.

1) If you get a lot of data in first file (a.py), it's will be better to keep them in list, not in variables.
For example,

```
n = 10 # count of values
lis = [int(input("enter value %d: " % x)) for x in range(1, n+1)]
```

You will have a list with 10 values, each of which was entered from the keyboard

2) To import data from a.py to calculate them in b.py write next code in b.py:

```
import a
print(a.lis[0]) # will print first value in list in a.py
for elem in a.lis:
    print(elem ** 2) # will print square of every value in list in a.py
```

or (if you won't write a.lis):

```
from a import *
print(lis[0]) # will print first value in list in a.py
for elem in lis:
    print(elem ** 2) # will print square of every value in list in a.py
```

Comment: Its oke, my English also not so good. Thank you sir... i learn five things in here, you really help newbe like me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.., i got it.